# Change picture when click the button using z-index

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change picture when clicked the button using if else statement however kind of confused only two pictures are changing when clicked .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function restack() {

        var x=document.getElementById('blueberries');
        var z=x.style.zIndex
        if (z==10) z=20;
        else if z=10;
          x.style.zIndex=z;
        else 
          i = 30;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle?.

Comment: Provide your HTML also.

Comment: <img src="apples.jpg" alt="apples" id="apples" 
    style="position: absolute; top: 62px; left: 0px; z-index: 20;" >
    
    <img src="blueberries.jpg" alt="blueberries" id="blueberries" 
    style="position: absolute;top: 88px; left: 90px; z-index: 10;">
    
    <img src="pumpkins.jpg" alt="pumpkins" id="pumpkins" 
    style="position: absolute;top: 0px; left: 90px; y-index: 10;" >
 
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="stack();">

Comment: function stack() {
    var x = document.getElementById('blueberries');
    var z = x.style.zIndex
   
    if (z == 10) z = 20 
     else 
      z = 10;
      x.style.zIndex = z;
      
    }

Comment: I am trying to change three pictures (0,1,2,0,1,2 repeating)  when I click the button.I can change two, but third one is not working ...